# sudo su - does not honor /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables

I have set a PATH variable in `/etc/environment`. When I log into my system as root, the path variable is correctly applied. However, when I log in as another user and then become root via

```
sudo su -
```

`/etc/environment` doesn't seem to get honoured. Why is that? How can I change it?

output of `grep readenv /etc/pam.d/su`:

```
# parsing /etc/environment needs "readenv=1"
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

cat /etc/lsbrelease:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

dpkg -S /bin/su:

```
login: /bin/su
```

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/sudo.8.html#description

Comment: Try: `sudo -E ...`

Comment: I'm aware I can keep my current environment variables. However, I would like to know why /etc/environment is not being honoured if I'm basically logging in as root.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `grep readenv /etc/pam.d/su`. What is your Ubuntu version? In particular, is `/bin/su` provided by the `login` or the `util-linux` package?